# Problem in running two Webcams in RaspberryPi simultaneously

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, webcam

I purchased two webcams ([Logitech C310 HD Webcam](https://www.amazon.in/Logitech-C310-HD-Webcam-Black/dp/B008QS9KMW)) to use with RaspberryPi (RPi 3 B+ model). When I run individual cameras, they are running fine but when I tried to run both cameras at the same time it didn't run. I came to know that it may be due to less power in Raspberry Pi, so I purchased a powered USB hub ([Power USB hub](https://www.amazon.in/Segolike-480Mbps-Speed-USB2-0-Adapter/dp/B0711MHVBJ)). When I attached both cameras with raspberry pi through a power USB hub, it shows an error.

```
    Unable to stop the stream: Invalid argument
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/pi/opencv-3.4.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 356
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "two cameras simu.py", line 7, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame1',frame1)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /home/pi/opencv-3.4.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

The code I used is:

```
  import cv2
import numpy as np
cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
while (1):
 _,frame1 = cam1.read()
 cv2.imshow('frame1',frame1)
 _,frame2 = cam2.read()
 cv2.imshow('frame2',frame2)
 k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
 if k == 27:
  break
cam1.release()
cam2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

While the same code I run in the laptop (in PyCharm) with the power USB hub attached, it works fine.

Why there is an error while trying to run two cameras with Raspberry Pi? How I can run two webcams using Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding at the top

```
from imutils import VideoStream
import imutils
```

then change the input source from your cameras accordingly for example

```
cam1 = VideoStream(src=0).start()
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: I used sudo pip install imutils and sudo pip3 isntall imutils both but no use. It shows the same error "No module named imutils". I am using geany. What to do? When I used import imutils in Python 3.5.3 shell, it shows no error.